# How do I return an empty result from an IDbCommandInterceptor in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm attempting to implement an `IDbCommandEnterceptor` in Entity Framework 6.  The job of the interceptor is to give me access to the query that *would* be executed, without actually executing the it.

The Interceptor is working, but when I block query execution with `interceptionContext.SuppressExecution()`, the code that caused the query to execute is throwing a `NullReferenceException` inside Entity Framework's `ToList` method. I'm assuming this is because `ToList` is trying to read the contents of the query result, which hasn't been set, since execution was blocked.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper'1.Finally()
>   at
>     System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper'1.SimpleEnumerator.Dispose()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator'1.Dispose()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable'1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable'1 source)    at
>   AgentOctal.EntityFramework.Hinter.Tests.DbContextTests.DbContext_ShouldAllowInteception()
>   in
>   C:\Users\uffnerb\source\repos\AgentOctal.EntityFramework.Hinter\AgentOctal.EntityFramework.Hinter.Tests\DbContextTests.cs:line
>   22

My current interception code looks like this:

```
internal partial class MyInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Intercepting query ({MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}): {command.CommandText}");
        interceptionContext.SuppressExecution();
        NotifyMonitor(interceptionContext.DbContexts, command.CommandText);
    }

    ...
    //5 other identical methods on IDbCommandInterceptor
    ...

}
```

An example of code that executes a query that gets intercepted would be:

```
var query = context.Contacts.Where(c => c.FirstName == "Bradley");
var results = query.ToList();  //Exception is thrown inside this call to ToList
```

What can I do to return an empty result after blocking execution, in a way that code trying to run queries is unaware that the query was intercepted and blocked?

Comment: Maybe add an if statement to check for null instead of simply assigning?

Comment: Check for `null` of *what*?  `query` is NOT `null`. The exception is being thrown from deep within entity framework (see the stack trace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `Result` to something (that will also suppress execution). For example:

```
public override void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Intercepting query ({MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}): {command?.CommandText ?? "{{no command text}}"}");            
    // dummy empty reader
    interceptionContext.Result = new DataTableReader(new DataTable());
    NotifyMonitor(interceptionContext.DbContexts, command.CommandText);
}
```

Comment: What is the appropriate value to set `Result` to for the `ScalarExecuting` method of the interface? Is `null` ok?

Comment: @BradleyUffner not sure really, maybe just `SuppressExecution()` like you do alrady will be fine. I'm not sure even which normal operation on EF context uses this `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: I'll give that a shot.  So far, none of my code is hitting that method, so I'll deal with it later, if it ever comes up.  Thank your for your help.